# Handling JSON object from .NET backend with Vue 3 frontend components

Tags: .net, entity-framework, vue.js, asp.net-web-api, vuejs3

I'm currently working on an SPA with Vue 3 and .NET Web API (EF core 5). I want to display a list of artists in which each artist has multiple genres associated with them. I have sucessfully made a many-to-many relationship between artist and genre in my webAPI:

**Artist.cs**

```
namespace API.Models {
    public class Artist {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Genre> Genres { get; } = new List<Genre>();
    }
}
```

**Genre.cs**

```
namespace FindAMusicianApi.Models {

    public class Genre {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Artist> Artists { get; } = new List<Artist>();

    }
}
```

**ArtistController.cs**

```
        public ArtistController( FindAMusicianContext context ) {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Artist>> Get() {
            List<Artist> artistList = await _context.Artists
            .Include(artist => artist.Genres)
            .ToListAsync();
            return artistList; 
        }
```

... and it works! When called via axios within my vue application I get this response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sarah Hyland",
    "description": "...",
    "genres": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pop",
        "artists": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Country",
        "artists": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Oscar Thomsen",
    "description": "... ",
    "genres": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Rock",
        "artists": []
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Hip Hop",
        "artists": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now to the issue at hand; I want to display all artists in an ArtistList:

**ArtistList.vue**

```
<template>
  <section class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <artist-item
      v-for="(artist, i) in artistList"
      :key="i"
      :id="artist.id"
      :name="artist.name"
      :description="artist.description"
      :genres="artist.genres"
    />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'
import ArtistItem from './ArtistItem'
export default {
  components: {
    ArtistItem,
  },
  setup() {
    const artists = reactive({ artistList: [] })
    axios('https://localhost:5001/artist/').then((response) => {
      artists.artistList = response.data
    })

    return { ...toRefs(artists) }
  },
}
</script>
```

via props from a component:

**ArtistItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100 bg-primary">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="d-inline-block mb-2 badge text-capitalize">{{ genres }}</p>
        <h3 class="card-title">{{ name }}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">{{ description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'ArtistDetails', params: { id: id } }" class="btn btn-dark">Read more</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    genres: Array,
  },
}
</script>
```

...  but `artist.genre` obviously outputs

```
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pop",
        "artists": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Country",
        "artists": []
      }
```

... and I of course only want the names of the genres in an array. I'm new to both .NET and Vue - if someone could please point me in the right direction I would be so happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do another v-for and use the objects name, You will want to add some commas after each one, maybe do a check if its the last item in the array and not display a comma if so. You could even just make a computed object as a string but its all up to you.

```
<template>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100 bg-primary">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="d-inline-block mb-2 badge text-capitalize">
            <span v-for="genre in genres" :key="genre.name">{{ genre.name }}</span>
        </p>
        <h3 class="card-title">{{ name }}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">{{ description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'ArtistDetails', params: { id: id } }" class="btn btn-dark">Read more</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    genres: Array,
  },
}
</script>
```

Below is with a computed object

```
<template>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100 bg-primary">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="d-inline-block mb-2 badge text-capitalize">{{ genreTags }}</p>
        <h3 class="card-title">{{ name }}</h3>
        <p class="card-text">{{ description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'ArtistDetails', params: { id: id } }" class="btn btn-dark">Read more</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    genres: Array,
  },
  computed: {
      genreTags() {
          const genres = this.genres.map(genre => {
              return genre.name
          });

          return genres.join(', ');
      }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! This works - no idea why I tought doing v-for in the item-component wouldnt work... Blame the hour! "You could even just make a computed object as a string" - care to give me an example of how that would look?

Comment: @trymv no worries at all, Ive updated my answer with the computed object, this will also take care of the commas,